# Find the general solution of the differential equation: $y' \sin y = x^2$ ;

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just started going through Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes
by George F. Simmons and came across this problem in the first exercise. From the given information I'm supposed to just integrate both sides. How do I integrate this particular problem to find the solution?

Comment: $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the whole, I find that differential equations (especially first order) are easier to think about if you put it in Leibniz notation. This becomes:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\, \sin(y) = x^2$$

Multiplying both sides by $dx$ yields:

$$\sin(y)\,dy = x^2\,dx$$

Now, when you integrate, just focus on the current expression:

$$\int sin(y)\,dy = \int x^2\,dx \\
-\cos(y) + C_1 = \frac{x^3}{3} + C_2 
$$

Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both unknown constants, they can be combined, yielding:

$$ -\cos(y) + C = \frac{x^3}{3}  \\
\frac{x^3}{3} + \cos(y) = C$$